# How to append a specific string to a URL that matches, constantly with Tampermonkey? Or another method?

Tags: javascript, youtube, tampermonkey

I want to append this string:

```
&sp=CAASAhAB
```

Every time a YouTube search query is performed to remove that stupid "People also watched" section.

I've created a Tampermonkey script that works pretty well but does not work when the search is performed by the website's own search box.

Could anyone help? Solving this would be great for posterity's sake.

Here's the TamperMonkey script:

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Youtube - Remove "People Also Watched" section from search results.
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1.1
// @description  Add "&sp=CAASAhAB" to YouTube search results URL if not already present. Recommended to also use https://github.com/Vulpelo/hide-youtube-shorts
// @author       MattFor | @mattfor | https://github.com/MattFor
// @match        www.youtube.com/results?search_query=*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    "use strict";

    function containsString(mainString, subString) {
        return mainString.indexOf(subString) !== -1;
    }

    function updateURL() {
        var currentURL = window.location.href;
        var queryString = "&sp=CAASAhAB";

        if (!containsString(currentURL, queryString)) {
            window.location.href += queryString;
        }
    }

    updateURL();

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", updateURL);
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", updateURL);
})();
```

---

**Edit #1**: Updated my code based on comments to the question yet there are no significant upgrades, looks like the YouTube POST request is only sent *once* judging by the network tab.

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Youtube - Modify search request
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1.1
// @description  Add "&sp=CAASAhAB" to YouTube search results URL if not already present.
// @author       MattFor | @mattfor | https://github.com/MattFor
// @match        www.youtube.com/results?search_query=*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    "use strict";

    function containsString(mainString, subString) {
        return mainString.indexOf(subString) !== -1;
    }

    function updateURL() {
        var currentURL = window.location.href;
        var queryString = "&sp=CAASAhAB";

        if (!containsString(currentURL, queryString)) {
            window.location.href += queryString;
        }
    }

    function modifySearchForm() {
        var searchForm = document.getElementById("search-form");

        if (searchForm) {
            searchForm.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var formAction = searchForm.action;
                var modifiedAction = formAction + "&sp=CAASAhAB";
                searchForm.action = modifiedAction;
                searchForm.submit();
            });
        }
    }

    updateURL();
    modifySearchForm();

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", updateURL);
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        updateURL();
        modifySearchForm();
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used Tampermonkey before, but I will take a stab at modifying your script to handle this.

The problem, as I see it is search functionality is controlled by a `<form action=""></form>` tag. Knowing this, the goal should be to modify that `action` parameter in the URL so it appends the `sp=CAASAhAB` URL parameter.

This *should* do it:

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Youtube - Remove "People Also Watched" section from search results.
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1.1
// @description  Add "&sp=CAASAhAB" to YouTube search results URL if not already present. Recommended to also use https://github.com/Vulpelo/hide-youtube-shorts
// @author       MattFor | @mattfor | https://github.com/MattFor
// @match        www.youtube.com/results?search_query=*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    "use strict";

    function containsString(mainString, subString) {
        return mainString.indexOf(subString) !== -1;
    }

    function updateURL() {

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Append the URL parameter to the URL.
        var currentURL = window.location.href;
        var queryString = "&sp=CAASAhAB";

        if (!containsString(currentURL, queryString)) {
            window.location.href += queryString;
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Append the URL parameter to the form action.
        var formAction = document.getElementById("search-form").action;
        var queryParam = "?sp=CAASAhAB";

        if (!containsString(formAction, queryParam)) {
            document.getElementById("search-form").action += queryParam;
        }

    }

    updateURL();

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", updateURL);
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", updateURL);
})();
```

If it doesn’t work, you might have intercept the form submit like this; pseudo code based on this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71708041/117259):

```javascript
document.querySelector("#search-form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.submitter.formAction += "&sp=CAASAhAB";
  this.submit();
})
```

Or a slight variant based on this other [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51611758/117259)

```javascript
document.querySelector("#search-form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  button.setAttribute("action", this.getAttribute("action") += "&sp=CAASAhAB");
  // Or try this instead of the above.
  // this.action += "&sp=CAASAhAB";
  this.submit();
});
```

Comment: Sadly this also doesn't do it. For some reason it just refuses to grab the event properly. Maybe there is another way to append this url with a different program?

There used to be a way with uBlock Origin as indicated [on this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/k76ext/lf_way_to_remove_people_also_watched_from_search/) but it does not work anymore.

Comment: Dunno. Let someone else try to wrestle this. But it is definitely the form submission that goes to a URL and that parameter should be appended to that URL. I did my best!

Comment: Thanks for contributing! After this problem is (hopefully) solved, I'm sure a lot of people will appreciate it. The search results page has been showing like 10 relevant things and then a bunch of crap for too long.